# How could GL_LINE_LOOP possibly draw triangles?

Tags: c++, opengl

As far as I can see from [OpenGL draw rectangle outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462209/opengl-draw-rectangle-outline) - given a proper array of vertices, GL_LINE_LOOP should draw a square.

So, I'm trying this Wavefront .obj file:

```
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 1.0 0.0
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
g myPlane
f 1 2 3 4
```

... and I would have expected x,y of (0,0) -> (1,0) -> (1,1) -> (0,1) would have provided a square. However, I'm trying this in a program which is a reduced version of the https://github.com/julianstorer/JUCE/blob/master/examples/Demo/Source/Demos/OpenGLDemo.cpp ... there it is used:

```
      attributes.enable (openGLContext);
      glDrawElements (GL_LINE_LOOP, vertexBuffer.numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); //GL_TRIANGLES
      attributes.disable (openGLContext);
```

... as C++ drawing code, and the output for the above .obj file is:

[image: juce]

... that is - there is a diagonal line, and I have no idea how it is possible for it to end up there, if I use GL_LINE_LOOP? (there are images like [this one](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/405/WWW/Lab2/glPrimitives.png) that show that GL_LINE_LOOP should not draw a diagonal for this sequence of vertices)? So why do I get a diagonal - what could be the problem causing it, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure your OBJ parser isn't decomposing n>3-gons into triangles?

Comment: Thanks @genpfault - I'm not sure of that; I manually wrote the file, I thought that was good enough, but I guess I better check the parser too... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by @genpfault, found that it is indeed the parser that decomposes into triangles; the parser is [WavefrontObjParser.h](https://github.com/julianstorer/JUCE/blob/master/examples/Demo/Source/Demos/WavefrontObjParser.h), and it contains, among other things:

```
struct Face
{
    Face (String::CharPointerType t)
    {
        while (! t.isEmpty())
            triples.add (parseTriple (t));
    }

    Array<TripleIndex> triples;
...
```

... which, I guess, indicates that the original mesh is split into a new mesh...